# redirect stdout and stderr to seperate files and to screen

Tags: redirect, stdout, stderr

I have been through quite a few variants of this question but none seems to do exactly what I want. I would like to start csh, have STDOUT go to one file and to the screen, and have STDERR go to a different file, and to the screen as well.

This command:
`csh > stdout_file.txt 2> stderr_file.txt`

gets STDOUT and STDERR to different files, but than nothing goes to the screen. How can I get what is written to the files go to the screen as well? I assume tee should be a part of this, but whatever I try gives my syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((csh | tee f1) >`tty`) 2>&1 | tee f2
```

or maybe

```
((csh | tee f1) >`tty`) |& tee f2
```

Comment: Works well, thanks a lot! For clarification for anyone reading this: f1 holds stdout, f2 holds stderr.